# Spring Boot / PCF / SAML / OKTA :: SAML 2.0 with Okta works fine with localhost, but fails with pcf route URL

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, okta, pcf

I have created a simple spring boot app with saml sso, using okta as the provider with the following details:

```
Single Sign On URL:   http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO
Recipient URL:        http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO
Destination URL:      http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO
Audience Restriction: http://localhost:8080/saml/metadata
```

I have pushed this app to PCF and updated the details as below:

```
Single Sign On URL:   https://pcf-saml-auth.cfapps.io/saml/SSO
Recipient URL:        https://pcf-saml-auth.cfapps.io/saml/SSO
Destination URL:      https://pcf-saml-auth.cfapps.io/saml/SSO
Audience Restriction: https://pcf-saml-auth.cfapps.io/saml/metadata
```

Where `pcf-saml-auth.cfapps.io` is my pcf route url.

After deploying to pcf, on successful login through okta, it keeps redirecting to login page again and again.

**Metadata URL:** `https://dev-254714.okta.com/app/exkapmmvkEKcamnci356/sso/saml/metadata`

If any one has faced similar issue, request you to please help me how to get it working and what is it that I am doing wrong here.

Thank you.